# Can i upload MERN app to bluehost server and run?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, server, bluehost

Hi everyone I have one question about deploying project. My project is made with MERN(MongoDB express js, react.js and node.js) also i have bluehost server where need to deploy this project.But i cant find how to deploy my app as node project, thanks for help :))